# 404 page on Docker when installing

Tags: docker

The docker page used to install on ubuntu returns a 404 ?  
get.docker.io/ubuntu

Does anyone know a work around for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this page: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I found that page originally and that's where i noticed that get.docker.io/ubuntu was broken. As it asks you to run this command: sudo sh -c "echo deb http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list" which fails due to the 404 ?

Answer (score 1):

Docker is currently only available on x86_64 platforms. It is not yet available for 32bit.